# PhpStorm debug showing same file twice

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

I have a simple index.php file set up for debug testing. When I select Run->Debug in the PhpStorm IDE, I see a popup menu that shows the index.php file twice. Debug only works if I select one of them. Does anyone know

1. Why is it showing twice?
2. Is there something I can do to make it only show once?

[image: Debug Menu]

I see there are different icons in the menu, but can't tell what they are or mean...

Answer (score 0):

Right after posting this, I figured it out.

Select the first option in that little menu, `Edit Configurations...`

Check the box marked `Single instance only`

[image]

Not sure why this works, so if anyone knows, please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two **different** debug configs:

1. First one is **JavaScript** debug in Google Chrome browser
2. Second one is **"PHP Script"** type of config -- to run/debug your php file in CLI environment.

---

You can check and edit your Run/Debug Configurations via drop down box on main toolbar (next to Run/Debug buttons) or via `Run | Edit Configurations...`.

You will notice there that both of these entries are:

1. Located under different roots ("JavaScript Debug" and "PHP Script" accordingly)
2. They are not "permanent" but temporary (icon is faded) which means that they were created automatically by IDE when you choose them for first time (either via context menu or by invoking hot key).